# Scalable seq -> groupby -> count

Tags: algorithm, f#

I have a very large unordered sequence of int64s - about O(1B) entries.  I need to generate the frequency histogram of the elements, ie:

```
inSeq
|> Seq.groupBy (fun x->x)
|> Seq.map (fun (x,l) -> (x,Seq.length l))
```

Let's assume I have only, say 1GB of RAM to work with. The full resulting map won't fit into RAM (nor can I construct it on the fly in RAM). So, of course we're going to have to generate the result on disk.  What are some performant ways for generating the result?
One approach I have tried is partitioning the range of input values and computing the counts within each partition via multiple passes over the data.  This works fine but I wonder if I could accomplish it faster in a single pass.

One last note is that the frequencies are power-law distributed.  ie most of the items in the list only appear only once or twice, but a very small number of items might have counts over 100k or 1M.  This suggests possibly maintaining some sort of LRU map where common items are held in RAM and uncommon items are dumped to disk.

F# is my preferred language but I'm ok working with something else to get the job done.

Comment: For each key, `Seq.groupBy` would store a large sequence of equivalent values, which are *discarded* at the very next step. Why wouldn't you use a mutable [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to compute just *number* of elements, not the elements itself? This would be a very straightforward O(n) algorithm.

Comment: Surely `Seq.countBy` would be pretty good here

Comment: We're computing a Dictionary<int64,int64> (value, count of value).  We're talking about a tree with 1e9 leaves * 16 bytes per leaf.  Way more than 1GB. The result has got to be cached to disk or we're going to thrash like crazy. [edit:] In unix-land we'd call sort|uniq -c.  Unix sort is smart about going to disk when the stream gets huge.  Maybe the right approach is to use the disk to sort the elements and then we can stream the sorted set to produce a stream of counts.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you're both addressing other issues with my code- Seq.countBy would be perfect if I could fit everything in RAM.  The real technical problem I have is the fact that the counts won't fit in RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have enough disk space for a copy of the input data, then your multiple passes idea really requires only two. On the first pass, read an element `x` and append it to a temporary file `hash(x) % k`, where `k` is the number of shards (use just enough to make the second pass possible). On the second pass, for each temporary file, use main memory to compute the histogram of that file and append that histogram to the output. Relative to the size of your data, one gigabyte of main memory should be enough buffer space that the cost will be approximately the cost of reading and writing your data twice.

Comment: Thanks, I like this option. I was looking at doing an [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) followed by a single pass, but this option limits the sorting to internal to the shards, probably saving me a pass.